# trying to set css styes from js get vanished when appending route in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set css style for a div on clicking the same div. on ng-click I update the 
 view with appending url as well as change the style of that div which has 
 been clicked. The view which I concern gets updated but style has not been 
 applied simultaneously. Style gets applied when i click on the div for the 
 second time.

### js

```
    if($location.search().MobileTransForm != undefined){
        $scope.showMobileTransForm = true;
        $("#mobileNoCard1").css('color', 'red');
    }
    else{
       console.log("inside else MobileTransForm");
    }

$scope.openMobileTransForm = function(){
    $("#mobileNoCard1").css('color', 'red');
    $location.path('/trans').search({MobileTransForm: 1});
    $scope.showMobileTransForm = true;
}
```

here `$scope.showMobileTransForm = true;` is there to show a new form as `ng-show = showMobileTransForm`. And `mobileNoCard1` is an `id` on which `ng-click` event set to trigger.

Comment: People are going to need to see the relevant code to help you solve this.

Comment: suggestion required.